# As3 Date Object Not Returning Hours Correctly

Tags: actionscript-3, date

So I have a really simple, yet annoying problem. I am creating a date object and calling the getHours() method and the return seems to always be zero. Perhaps I am doing something wrong?

```
var d:Date = new Date(1382166000000); // 10 / 19 / 13 @ 2:00:00am EST
trace(d.getTime() + " : " + d.getHours());

//output: 1382166000000 : 0
```

Any ideas? Unless I am monumentally confused shouldn't getHours be returning 2?

Comment: You sure about this? I seem to be getting 1382166000000 : 2.

Comment: Yup, I copied and pasted the code exactly from my As3 document. Perhaps it could be related to my machine's time settings? (Also I am exporting for AIR 3.4 if that might impact things?)

Comment: Yes, it is affected by the local machine's time zone settings. However, if it is set correctly, it should represent the same time in every time zone. (as far as I know, at least)

Comment: Ya, it is really weird, I just tried in a fresh As3 document containing only those 2 lines of code exactly as it is above and it still printed out 0 for the hours.

Comment: var d:Date = new Date(1382166000000); // 10 / 19 / 13 @ 2:00:00am EST
trace(d.getTime() + " : " +  (d.getHours() + d.timezoneOffset / 60)); should give you : 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Date` doesn't work the way you think it does. It can exist in one of two formats: the local time or UTC.

The `getHours()` method returns local time, or the UTC time formatted according to the computer's internal timezone offset. The time you passed is actually 7AM in UTC. So by that logic, you (and I) are in PST (or UTC-7). If you run `d.timezoneOffset`, it should return `420`, which is 7 hours in minutes.

Now, most of the time you **never** want to work with anything except UTC (UTC is a constant, especially in computers). So forget the `getHours()` method and look at `getUTCHours()` instead.

```
trace(d.getTime() + " : " + d.getUTCHours ()); // output 1382166000000 : 7
```

So that will give you the time in UTC hours. Next, you have to determine what time zone you want to format it as. EST is UTC-5, so you want to subtract 5 from the UTC hours.

```
trace(d.getTime() + " : " + ( d.getUTCHours () - 5 )); // output 1382166000000 : 2
```

And that gives you exactly what you were expecting.

Just to reiterate: AS3's `Date` class **does not** allow for setting the timezone. You only have access to the time in UTC and in the local time zone. Nothing more. If you want time in any other time zone, you need to format it manually, as I did above.