# How to get IST(Indian Standard Time) time using actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, gmt

I need to access the ISTusing as3. I don't need system time because i want exact IST.I have tried getTimezoneOffset(), but it shows the difference b/w IST and GMT irrespective of current system time.In my case i strictly needed the IST from the internet with out using the system time.
Could you help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: See my answer to this question. Should explain how to do it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460108/as3-date-object-not-returning-hours-correctly/19460480#19460480

Answer (score 0):

May be this help you what you want.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>time test</title>
<script>


function getTime(zone, success) {
var url = 'http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz=' + zone,
    ud = 'json' + (+new Date());
window[ud]= function(o){
    success && success(new Date(o.datetime));
};
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild((function(){
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.src = url + '&callback=' + ud;
    return s;
})());
}

getTime('GMT', function(time){
// This is where you do whatever you want with the time:
alert(time);
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML=time;
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="time"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```